# Why doesn't Solmate's SafeTransferLib.sol just revert when iszero(success)?

Tags: solidity, assembly

In SafeTranserLib.sol by Solmate why don't they just check if the external call was successful like this:

```
if iszero(success) {
    revert(0,0)
}
```

And then revert.

Instead they do all this fancy stuff with the logic operators but I don't really see the point. Why do we need to check if the returndatasize is gt 31 when we know that the call was successful.

Here is the code from Solmate:

```js
success := and(
    // Set success to whether the call reverted, if not we check it either
    // returned exactly 1 (can't just be non-zero data), or had no return data.
    or(
        and(eq(mload(0), 1), gt(returndatasize(), 31)),
        iszero(returndatasize())
    ),
    // We use 100 because the length of our calldata totals up like so: 4 + 32 * 3.
    // We use 0 and 32 to copy up to 32 bytes of return data into the scratch space.
    // Counterintuitively, this call must be positioned second to the or() call in the
    // surrounding and() call or else returndatasize() will be zero during the computation.
    call(gas(), token, 0, freeMemoryPointer, 100, 0, 32)
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transferFrom` function returns a boolean which will be abi.encoded (32 bytes long) and can be either `true` (1) or `false` (0). Additionally, the `call` instruction will "return" either 0 (call reverted) or 1 (call succeed).

So :

1. If the call reverts : success = 0
2. If the call succeeds and returns false : success = 0
3. If the call succeeds and returns true : success = 1

All those cases would be handled with the following code :

```
success := and(
    // > 31 bytes of return data and returned True
    and(eq(mload(0), 1), gt(returndatasize(), 31)),
    // low level call succeeded
    call(gas(), token, 0, freeMemoryPointer, 100, 0, 32)
)
```

Now for the `iszero(returndatasize())` part, it comes down to a "breaking change" that made several (wrong) ERC-20 implementations behave differently. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca), but basically their implementation is :

```
 function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external;
```

Instead of what the ERC-20 standard dictates :

```
 function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
```

To accommodate for those (even though they are wrong as they do not strictly implement ERC-20) there is a special case :

- If the low level call succeeds and there is no return data : success = 1

This is what the following piece of code is handling :

```
or(..., iszero(returndatasize()))
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: How can a call succeed and the success var be false? If it returns false the success var should be true and the return data should be just 0x00 no?

Comment: The low level call can succeed (i.e., not revert) if the implementation returns false instead of reverting, in that case the `transferFrom` logic failed since it returned false, but the low level call succeeded, `safeTransferFrom` must treat that as a failure.